# Question about self homomorphism of dyadic rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

I'm reading a paper that uses the group $D = \{j/2^n \mid j \in \mathbb{Z}, n \geq 0\}$ and they define a homomorphism $h: D \rightarrow D$ determined by $h(1) = j/2^n$ for some odd $j$ and positive integer $n$.  My question is, how can one determine $h(m/2^j)$ for any other $m/2^j \in D$.  I don't believe one can treat it as a ring homomorphism since I already tried doing that and arrived at getting something not in $D$.  Also, they say that the image of $h$ is a subgroup of odd index.  Why is that?  Sorry if this question seems kind of trivial, my group theory knowledge and skills are lacking and I'd rather ask someone who knows rather than pour through books at the moment.

Comment: There is no $k$ before the vertical bar in definition of $D.$ Leaves it not clearly defined...

Comment: @coffeemath sorry that’s supposed to be a j

Comment: Now it's corrected, will delete my comment later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h(1)$ being determined, $h(n)$ is clearly determined fo $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

The point is now that multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$ is special : $n\times m = m +....+m$ where there are $n$ $m$'s (if $n\geq 0$). So, say you want to determine $h(\frac{j}{2^n})$. Then look at $h(j) = h(2^n \frac{j}{2^n}) = h(\frac{j}{2^n} +...+\frac{j}{2^n}) = h(\frac{j}{2^n}) +...+h(\frac{j}{2^n}) = 2^n h(\frac{j}{2^n})$.

Now in $D$, for all $a$, the equation (unknown $x$) $2^n x = a$ has exactly one solution, and that is $x=\frac{a}{2^n}$.

So in the end we get $h(\frac{j}{2^n}) = \frac{jh(1)}{2^n}$. That's why the value of $h(1)$ completely determines $h$

Comment: I was trying to do something along these lines but for some reason kept getting nowhere.  Basic algebra after all...Thanks!!!

Comment: Another thing they're saying about $D$ is that every non-zero element of $D$ has a unique representation $j/2^n$ for an odd number $j$ and non-negative integer $n$.  How is that possibly true?  What about 2?  Isn't 2 in $D$?  There's simply no way this can be expressed in the form they describe.

Comment: As you point out, this is clearly not true. It works if $n$ is allowed to be negative, and this allows you to keep uniqueness (but then might as well say $j2^n$ with $j$ odd and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ )